# Calculate sample size from simulated results

Tags: sample-size, effect-size

I have a dataset of multiple purchases of the same product from a group of individuals. I aim to simulate the impact of increasing the pricing if the quantity of the purchased product by customers exceeds a specific value. I also assume that the increase in pricing might lead some customers to no longer purchase the product. To assess the total revenue after the increase, I bootstrap the dataset by randomly reducing it by x%, where x represents the percentage of churners.

In the simulation, I compare the total revenue of the increased pricing experiment (excluding churned customers) with the actual total revenue from the data, obtaining the expected revenue increase (or decrease) in percentage: ((Total new revenue - Actual revenue) / Actual revenue). I repeat the simulation N times, resulting in a distribution of the ratio increases.

Now, assuming I want to propose an actual experiment to the company, I need to determine the sample size to ensure that the results observed between a control group and the test group are statistically relevant (with a significance level of 0.05 and a power of 80%). To calculate the sample size, I must provide the effect size. Given that, from my simulations, the average percentage increase is 2.01% with a standard deviation of 0.02, it makes sense to use the standardized effect size as the ratio between 2.01/0.02?

I am aware that the standard deviation that I get from bootstrapping is underestimating the real one, so the standard deviation is way too small. I am also aware that such a high standardized sample size is also too large to use for a power analysis to estimate the sample size. I am tempted to just use 2.01% as the estimated effect size. Any comments and suggestions on the way I've set this up are also welcome!